# Are there certain countries that a black African traveler should avoid travelling to?

Tags: india, asia, africa, discrimination

I'm in my 20s and originally from East Africa. I live in Ireland but have traveled across Western Europe and to the US/Canada. I've found very little racism there contrary to popular belief.

I would like to travel to South America/Asia and some have told me that I should be concerned about racial issues. Apparently countries like India, Japan, Brazil etc.. don't treat black people that well. Is this fear-mongering or is there some truth to it?

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page [Racism by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism_by_country) that might be of interest, linking to other pages per country.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question objectively. Hence closing as opinion based.

Comment: " popular belief" is NOT a reliable source of information

Comment: I think the question can be answered (in a more-or-less objective manner) for specific countries, but as written it's a bit vague. Probably someone has answers for India, or for Japan, or for Brazil, but a global view of the question is going to be difficult.

Comment: And the answer depends on the place: tourist places? business district? Country-side? And the type of travellers (rich tourist, vs. backpacker/hitch-hiker). I recommend you to reformulate the question: Tell us where do you want to go, and ask about tips to remain safe.

Comment: Its a highly subjective question, but I would stick with Japan, South Korea or Taiwan over mainland China if you go to Asia.  The air is cleaner, the people are nicer.  Racism in mainland China is is common and generally accepted as normal.  Here's a good example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Few8kJ0zfnY